# How can I convert this to CSS?

Tags: css

I've edited this in inspector and wanted it to be implemented in CSS.

```
    <div id="av_section_1" class="avia-section main_color avia-section-default avia-no-border-styling avia-full-stretch avia-bg-style-scroll  avia-builder-el-0  el_before_av_section  avia-builder-el-first  av-minimum-height av-minimum-height-custom container_wrap fullsize" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(https://download.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: top right; " data-section-bg-repeat="stretch">
```

Can someone help me convert this to CSS and have it over ride what will be there?

Thanks

Comment: move it to the bottom of your css and add the !important directive.

Comment: okay what about the id?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class and give it some name, say `someClass` into your `CSS` file :

```
.someClass {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-image: url(https://download.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg) !important; 
    background-attachment: scroll !important; 
    background-position: top right !important;
}
```

Then modify your div tag as follows :

```
 <div id="av_section_1" class="avia-section main_color avia-section-default avia-no-border-styling avia-full-stretch avia-bg-style-scroll  avia-builder-el-0  el_before_av_section  avia-builder-el-first  av-minimum-height av-minimum-height-custom container_wrap fullsize someClass" data-section-bg-repeat="stretch"></div>
```

Just to explain a bit, the use of `!important` will override any other value of the same property. Hence the `someClass` will be completely applied.

Just to let you know, I am not really comfortable using so many classes on your div tag. I'd suggest minimizing the number of classes for simpler maintainability.

NOTE : 
You could also do it inline as follows :

```
<div id="av_section_1" class="avia-section main_color avia-section-default avia-no-border-styling avia-full-stretch avia-bg-style-scroll  avia-builder-el-0  el_before_av_section  avia-builder-el-first  av-minimum-height av-minimum-height-custom container_wrap fullsize someClass" data-section-bg-repeat="stretch" style="background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-image: url(https://download.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg) !important;background-attachment: scroll !important;background-position: top right !important;"></div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yea so it's in wordpress so I don't think I can set the class.

Answer (score 0):

Satwik has given you a lot of good advice.  But, I would recommend a slightly different solution, excluding `!important`.  Try this!

CSS:

```
.your-class {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-image: url(https://download.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg); 
   background-attachment: scroll; 
   background-position: top right;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="av_section_1" class="avia-section main_color avia-section-default avia-no-border-styling avia-full-stretch avia-bg-style-scroll  avia-builder-el-0  el_before_av_section  avia-builder-el-first  av-minimum-height av-minimum-height-custom container_wrap fullsize your-class" data-section-bg-repeat="stretch"></div>
```

If you try this without success, consider using order and specificity to make sure that your CSS is being applied as you'd like.  `!important` is a valuable debugging tool, but should not be left in your deployed code.

The last CSS written will override prior CSS.  So make sure that `.your-class` is at the bottom of your stylesheet and that you are not calling other stylesheets *after* the stylesheet that you are working in.

If you are still having trouble, see these links to learn about specificity:

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

I would also recommend consolidating some of your classes.  You may find it valuable to really dig into the sites mentioned above.  Developing good habits based on best practices will be crucial moving forward and potentially working with others.